# How do I go about breaking apart this image into two separate lines with opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have this image that I'd like to break into 2 separate diagonal lines by removing the vertical line using opencv. I thought about dilation, but this makes the lines I want to process even thinner, and more difficult to detect. What else can I do to remove the vertical line?

This is for video and the unwanted line isn't always vertical, but is more upright than the other two.

[image: Two diagonal lines, and an unwanted vertical line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use morphological opening. Shape of the structuring element matters here. Use a rectangular element having width greater than the width of the vertical line, and a height of 1.

In the given image, the width of the vertical line is 4, therefore using the following:

getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(5, 1))

I get

[image]

Comment: I chose this answer for the explanation about the vertical rectangular element. Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Though, as I understand a morphological opening is two morphological operations together?

Comment: Yes, erosion followed by a dilation

Answer (score 1):

First, use the **erosion** function ([**erode()**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode)) until the vertical line disappears. Then, just use **dilation** ([**dilate()**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate)) - the diagonal lines will get thicker again, and your unwanted vertical line is not going to reappear. It will also work in cases when the unwanted line is not vertical - it is enough for the unwanted line to be thinner than the lines you want to stay. The lines to stay don't have to be diagonal as well - it's enough that they are thicker enough than the unwanted lines, and they may have any orientation and direction.

Comment: I was having problems with the erosion of lines that I wanted to keep, so, although the erosion/dilation is part of the process that I've done, the answer about the element shape really nailed it for me! Thanks